# Comportamento da Variável this em Validation com Mongoose + Nodejs

Tags: javascript, mongoose, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando executar um processo de validação para um campo no schema do mongoose. Porém, o comportamento da variável "this" está diferente do esperado. Pois de acordo com a documentação em: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators-and-this, deveria referenciar ao objeto do modelo que está sendo salvo.
Porém, ao debugar no VsCode a referencia Local ao this está correta, porém, a referência apontada pelo "Watcher" é outra, a referência da classe do módulo.
Alguém sabe me dizer porque isso ocorre?
Como acessar a referencia do this correto neste contexto?

[image: Exemplo do Debug]

Answer (score 0):

Resposta publicada em:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528416/behavior-of-this-variable-in-validation-with-mongoose-nodejs/51528619#51528619

Não se pode usar Arrow functions para se ter acesso ao contexto do this.